# jQuery Conflict - Using jQuery-noconflict

Tags: jquery

Well I read some threads and jquery's wiki but somehow I can't fix my problem.

Trying to add jQuery.noConflict() because some jQuery libraries conflict if I run. If I add jQuery.noConflict() like it has been told on jQuery Wiki. Both scripts will not work.

The Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

});
```

If i add here jQuery.noConflict()

```
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this-

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function(){
    // code using jQuery
});
```

If this doesn't work try making a fiddle with html,css and js and give a link in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use it like :

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.noConflict();

    // then the code stuff
  });
```

see if works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this (from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });

  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: What about conflicts between two or more jQuery Codes? I am using only jQuery Codes and no other library's. I am using the same code as you shared but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @karabey: Sorry, I missed that part. Just curious, why are you using multiple jQuery instances?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the code into something like this

```
(function($){
   // code using jQuery with $.
}(jQuery));
```

This will be called on document ready and you will no longer need the `$.noConflict();`